# sql server The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.

please help me correct the below query.

```
BEGIN TRAN      
COMMIT TRAN        
   --RETURN @pOrgID        
  END        

  print @Increment        

  SET @Increment=@Increment+1        
  END        

  print 'test'        

  Update table1 Set status='DONE',Processeddatetime=getutcdate() where OAPermID=@POAPermID         
   and Systemstartdatetime=@pSystemstartdatetime and BatchID=@BatchID        

   Update table1 Set status='DONE' where Organizationid=@POAPermID and status='pending' and BatchID=@BatchID        

 END TRY
```

Comment: There appears to be code missing here. There's no `BEGIN TRY` for starters. Please ensure all relevant code is included and that you format the block as code with proper indentation so we more easily read it and help out.

Answer (score 0):

Please complete the query next time

```
  begin try
  begin transaction
  declare @Increment as int = 0
print @Increment
set @Increment=@Increment+1
print 'test'
Update table1 Set status='DONE',Processeddatetime=getutcdate() where OAPermID=@POAPermID
and Systemstartdatetime=@pSystemstartdatetime and BatchID=@BatchID
Update table1 Set status='DONE' where Organizationid=@POAPermID and status='pending' and BatchID=@BatchID
  commit transaction
    end try
  begin catch
  declare @xact_status as varchar(30) = cast(xact_state() as varchar(30))
  select error_number() as errornumber, error_line() as errorline, error_message() as errormessage,
         error_procedure() as errorprocedure, error_state() AS errorState, error_severity() as errorseverity,
         @xact_status as exactstatus
  rollback transaction       
  end catch
```